# Adding tabs below the action bar

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my android application I have implemented a tab layout with swipeable views. Here is my MainActivity class:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class CustomerComplainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "New Complain", "Previous Complains" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);





    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}

And this is my TabPager Adapter class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new NewComplain();
    case 1:
        return new PreviousComplains();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 2;
}
```

}

This is  my activity_main.xml file.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AdminMainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#800000"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

This works, but the problem is the tabs are adding into the actiob bar as following.

[image]

But I want to add these tabs below the action bar. I would be much appreciated if anyone plz be so kind enough to explain how can I solve this problem.

Thanx in advance

Comment: This is the default behaviour when you use action bar with `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. You would have to look at different solutions, i.e. not using tabs for action bar.

Comment: But I followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) tutorial. It works fine.But when I use it in my app it doesn't.

Comment: On which device do you test it? Or on emulator? The normal behaviour is: if there's enough room (on tablets or in landscape mode), the tabs are displayed in the action bar. Otherwise they are displayed below the action bar.

Comment: I am testing with an emulator

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. I found the solution by replacing this line

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

with

```
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

and your problem is solved.